# Keyword Spotting: How to train a model with general speech corpus?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, transfer-learning, speech-recognition

I am trying to find a correct way to train a DNN based keyword spotting (Deep KWS) with general speech corpus (VS data) described in [this paper](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/zh-TW//pubs/archive/42537.pdf) (Chen, Guoguo, Carolina Parada, and Georg Heigold. "Small-footprint keyword spotting using deep neural networks." In Acoustics, speech and signal processing (icassp), 2014 ieee international conference on, pp. 4087-4091. IEEE, 2014.)

In section 2.2 **Transfer learning**, it said

> we use a deep neural network for
>   speech recognition with suitable topology to initialize the hidden
>   layers of the network. All layers are updated in training. Transfer
>   learning has the potential advantage that the hidden layers can
>   learn a better and more robust feature representation by exploiting
>   larger amounts of data and avoiding bad local optima.

Later in section 4.1 **Data**, it said

> The first set is a general speech
>   corpus, which consists of 3,000 hours of manually transcribed utterances
>   (referred to as VS data). The second set is a keyword specific
>   data (referred to as KW data), which included around 2.3K training
>   examples for each keyword, and 133K negative examples, comprised
>   of anonymized voice search queries or other short phrases

My question is: how do I train a feature representation layers?

AFAIK, the training procedures are using general speech corpus to train feature extraction layers at first, and using keyword (KW) data to train a keyword specific model. But I don't know how to undertake the first step.

For example, currently I have Wall Street Journal (WSJ) dataset which has about 18000 lexicons. Does it mean that I have to use 18000+1 (1 for silence state) output labels (classes) when undertaking the first step?

Comment: Why the downvote? Is this question not supposed to be here?

Comment: Please type your question as text, do not just post an image.